# отступы окна в браузере

Tags: html, css

[image: проблема в отображении]

Доброго времени суток! Ниже на картинке мое окно div делает оступы от верхнего и нижнего body никогда не сталкивался с этим. До этого другие сайты такого не выдавали и окна были вплотную и этих отступов не было. Надеюсь,несложно сформулировал.)

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: отступ слева исчез

Comment: @Сamper padding:0px;

Comment: отступ сверху остался

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте этот код в head

```html
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: все работает написал в style.css

Comment: @Сamper если все работает и решение вам помогло, принято отмечать ответ как правильный (галочка тапните)

Comment: @MidNightElf думал , что работает - нашел ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

решение

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

}